# belong usage in grammar

Tags: grammar

What is the correct usage of the word "belong in the following two sentences ?

These individuals are belong to that party. 
These individuals are belonging to that party.

Do I need to use "ing" for the word "belong" after "are"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither expression is correct.

- *Are belong* (*BE + infinitive*) is not a legitimate English construction.
- *Are belonging* is a legitimate construction, the progressive; but *belong* is a stative verb like *be* or *know* or *love*, and statives are not ordinarily used in the progressive.

What you want is the *simple present*:

> These individuals belong to that party.